# Way to get drawables in for loop recursively?

Tags: android, loops, android-drawable

I want to getDrawables in recursive mode and then add to an existing GridView. So then I'll set the layoutparams, the id, etc. 
Any idea?

Comment: !Warning drawable  files may contain some resource.xmls too you are about to get an error if you don;t handle that

Comment: @Charuka So If I have 300 drawables how can I do it? Setting manually at my xml layout?

Comment: @Charuka I'll see, thanks.